# find all the of the containing elements within a div - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this string:

#### STRING:

```
"<div class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon 
 Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-
 contents'>- wrong</div></div><div class='break'><div class='name-and-
 date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>
 </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></div><div 
 class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson 
 - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
 okay what is the matter with you.</div></div><div class='break'><div 
 class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:50 PM 
 Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- Bro!</div></div>"
```

In this string there is a div that has the class of "break". I'm trying to remove the last occurrence of that div and all that it contains.

So from that string I want this to return:

### HOPING FOR THIS RETURN:

```
"<div class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon 
 Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-
 contents'>- wrong</div></div><div class='break'><div class='name-and-
 date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>
 </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></div><div 
 class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson 
 - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
 okay what is the matter with you.</div></div>"
```

#### CURRENT ATTEMPT:

```
compliance_string.scan(/<div class='break'>/).last
```

But that just returns the div not all of the containing elements and it's contents.

Comment: use oga or nokogiri to parse your html. Makes your life easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nokogiri` gem

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html_string)
html_doc.css('.break:last-child').to_s
=> "<div class=\"break\">\n<div class=\"name-and-date\"><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:50 PM \n Eastern</strong></div>\n<div class=\"note-contents\">- Bro!</div>\n</div>"
```

Comment: This is great. Do you know how I remove that from the string?

Comment: What do you mean? you want everything in your string except this?

Comment: Yes. Everything but that just curious.

Comment: just call `html_doc.css('.break:last-child').remove`

Comment: I screwed up @ursus I actually need that last element to be removed and I need the string to be returned in the exact way but without that last div... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You can just `gsub()` it away – `compliance_string.gsub!(html_doc.css('.break:last-child').to_s, '')`

Comment: @Bitwise `html_doc.css('.break:last-child').remove` and then `html_doc.css('.break').to_s` should give what you want. is that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = "<div class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon 
 Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-
 contents'>- wrong</div></div><div class='break'><div class='name-and-
 date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>
 </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></div><div 
 class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson 
 - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
 okay what is the matter with you.</div></div><div class='break'><div 
 class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:50 PM 
 Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- Bro!</div></div>"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
last_div = page.xpath("//div[@class='break'][last()]")
puts last_div.to_s
```